# ng-content inside a Listview isn't being injected with content

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a component named `ItemsSelector` which contains a `ListView` :

```
<ListView class="list-group" [items]="[1,22,34,6]" style="height:1250px">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ListView>
```

This is how I use the `ItemsSelector` component:

```
<StackLayout class="home-panel">
    <ItemsSelector>
        <ng-template let-item="$implicit" let-i="index">
            <Label [text]="'111'" color="black"></Label>
            <Label [text]="'222'" color="black"></Label>
        </ng-template> 
    </ItemsSelector>
<StackLayout>
```

But it seems that  `ng-content` is not being injected with content , And it display items not like I wanted

[image]

BTW - According to  the [**docs**](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/list-view) , this is the way how to use `Listview`  :

[image]

So all I was doing is to send the view from outside , but without success...

**Question:**

Why isn't `ng-content` being injected with the content I provide ?

[**Playground**](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=FoJlN4&v=5)

Comment: What's the reason for downvote ?

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=s3Nqun

Comment: @yurzui I don't have any words left.  like always. I envy your brilliants.    

Comment: *brilliance.......

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you use `ng-template` you are actually passing a template and not the content directly.

Hence instead of using `<ng-content>` you need to use `<ng-container>` and `ngTemplateOutlet`.

In your ItemSelector.component.ts, import `TemplateRef, ContentChild` from `@angular/core`

Now declare a template inside the class as such: `@ContentChild(TemplateRef) template;`

Now in your ItemSelector.component.ts, you can call the template like this:

```
<ListView class="list-group" [items]="[1,22,34,6]" style="height:1250px">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
</ListView>
```

After you have done the above step, if you see, you are now passing some content to the `ListView` component as well.

So in the `ListView.component.html`, you now have to implement `<ng-content>`

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I've tried like you say , but still I don't see the items i'm injecting : https://i.imgur.com/bReWrVz.jpg , I see the same pic like in my question

Comment: The thing is that now you are passing some template again to the ListView component. So you have to make the same changes in your ListView component.ts and HTML as well.

Comment: What changes ? can you please elaborate ? it's a simple task which doesn't work. ngcontent......

Comment: Royi, whenever you call a component say <abc>Something here</abc>. you need to either have an ng-content, or ng-container in the abc component html. If you look at the code above, you have passed template to <ItemSelector> so you have <ng-container> in ItemSelector.html, but now, you are also passing content to the <listView> component, so you need to have an <ng-content> in the listview.component.html as well.

Comment: <ListView class="list-group" [items]="[1,22,34,6]" style="height:1250px">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
</ListView>
The ng-container will be replaced with some content which is being passed to listView. So to display that content, you have to have <ng-content> in listView component.html

Comment: I've changed it to what you wrote , I still see the image result

Comment: Can you create a plunkr for me?

Comment: It's a nativescript plunker https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=FoJlN4&v=5

Comment: I can't see the image because it is denied on my office network. I also need to make changes to other components. :-/

Comment: See this link , and the apps from right bottom : https://play.nativescript.org/?template=groceries-ng&tutorial=groceries-ng